# Frequency of unique values of one variable grouped in another variable - R?

Tags: r

Extreme newbie question: I have 2 variables, region ID and household ID, there are duplicate households within the regions. I'm just trying to find out how many unique households are in each region.

This is what I am trying:

```
library(dplyr)

table <- data %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise(hid = unique(hid))
```

> Error message: 
>   Error: Column `hid` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 142

Comment: You may need `summarise(hid = toString(unique(hid)))` and paste as a single stirng or create a `list` and `unnest` `%>%summarise(hid = list(unique(hid))) %>% unnest(c(hid))`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might get you what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(region_id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
       household_id = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"))

df %>% 
  group_by(region_id) %>% 
  count(household_id) %>% 
  summarize(unique_households = n())
```